# ASP.NET MVC using ADAL library for ADFS 2016 - How to request access tokens for different APIs (audiences)

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, adfs, adal

The following code below is used to authenticate users in ADFS 2016 and to request an Access Token for the resource defined in cp.APIBaseURL:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var cp = UnityConfig.Container.Resolve<IConfigurationProvider>();
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = cp.ClientId,
                    MetadataAddress = cp.MetadataAddress,
                    RedirectUri = cp.RedirectUri,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = cp.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
                    ResponseType = "code id_token",
                    Scope = "openid",
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived 
                    }
                });


 private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
        {
            var cp = UnityConfig.Container.Resolve<IConfigurationProvider>();

            AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(
                configurationProvider.Authority, false,
                new InMemoryTokenCache(context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Name));

            AuthenticationResult ar = await ac.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                context.Code, new Uri(cp.RedirectUri),
                new ClientCredential(cp.ClientId, cp.ClientSecretKey),
                cp.APIBaseURL);
        }
```

I would like to know how to change the code to request a 2nd Access Token for a different API (having a different audience)?

Can I also specify different scopes for the 2nd Access Token I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `result = await ac.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, clientId);` to request the access token for different resouces. Refer [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token) for more details.

> Can I also specify different scopes for the 2nd Access Token I need?

No,for v1(adal) Azure AD apps, scopes must be statically configured in the Azure Portal under the **API permissions**, configured permissions.

Comment: Did not work. I received a _"Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (BadRequest)."_ Please note that we are using ADFS and not Azure AD.